# BCM4313 Wireless Adapter on 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I realize that there is a lot of talk about wireless drivers, as well as a lot of suggested solutions. I believe I have tried a lot of them and am now with a new install open to new suggestions.

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Does not react to any of the drivers explained in this very detailed and otherwise useful [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx).

It has been suggested that for a 14e4:4727 it shouldn't be necessary to install any drivers as they are "installed by default in the package linux-firmware".

As this did not work I latter tried with drivers suggested by "Additional drivers" with same lack of result. As of course with the rest of the mentioned drivers. I did not use several drivers at the same time.

I should also say that`rfkill list`does not show anything blocked and the wireless adapter is on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the setup process for the 14e4:4727 adapter using the [second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/193204) of the question you linked to. The brcmsmac driver should be install by default, as you said. What you'll need to do is remove the other drivers like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
```

and reboot, after that it should work!

I also read around about editing `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to disable the other drivers, but I didn't think this configuration was worth it since I won't be changing my wireless network adapter hardware configuration any time soon.

**EDIT**: I expanded on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/299916/193204) to build the right strategy to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Acer Aspire with BCM 4313 has run problem free since 2012 with Ubuntu 12.04 and recently 14.04 using Linsys Routers and occasionally a Netgear Extender.

A recent upgrade to Hiltron CGN3 Duel Band Router was a problem for BCM 4313 which although signed on to the SSID would not connect to the internet.

The issue was resolved by a simple change to the CGN3's Basic 2.4G Wireless Settings:

Factory setting on Wireless Mode: 802.11 b/g/n mixed

Wireless Mode RESET to 802.11 b/g

BCM 4313 connection problem was resolved by the above reset.